# Airflow with Docker connect to a local Host PostgreSQL

Tags: docker, airflow

I am running airflow with docker.

I want to go query some data in my PostgresSQl which on my local host.

this is my connection in my dag:

```
def queryPostgresql():
    conn_string="dbname='datawarehouse' host='localhost' user='postgres' password='admin'"
    conn=db.connect(conn_string)
    df=pd.read_sql("select name,city from test",conn)
    df.to_csv('data.csv')
    print("-------Data Saved------")
```

I am adding a connection to airflow:

[image]

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Is it possible to query in my PgSQL from my Airflow Docker? Should I instead install PgSQL in docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to access `localhost` in Airflow, it's trying to connect to Postgres running on the Airflow container, which is not there. `localhost` from a container does not route to the Docker host machine by default.

Couple of options:

- Connect to the Docker host with `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`
- Run Airflow and Postgres in a Docker Compose network and connect via container name (`psql` etc.)

There are a few other methods with hosts files etc. but the above is likely your easiest options.